# Where to check Email send from Process builder after 10 days of a particular date

Tags: email, process-builder, email-alert, process

I have one process builder which has one scheduled action, which will send one email alert after 10 days of a particular date.

I want to check whether this email alert is send or not. Where can I check this?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a specific example, you can use the Email Log to see all emails sent by SFDC on the day in question to verify it was sent.

You have some other options as well

a) Add a Task to the target object that is created the same time the Email Alert is sent. The Task acts as a proxy for the email with respect to easy logging/verification

b) [Enable Enhanced Email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_enhanced_email_considerations.htm&type=0&language=en_US) . Email body will appear in activity history.

Comment: How to add Enhanced Email related list to object?

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper - my bad; edited post